# Database design: Which will perform better, auto incremented column or a composite key for appointments

Tags: database-design, primary-key

The schema of table is :

```
appointment(date,time,patientID,...)
pateint(patientID,PName,age,...)
```

PS: two or more patient can came at the same time .
    The number of appointments per day up to 500 .

Which is better for performance, using auto-incremented primary key or a composite primary key (date,time,pateintID)?

Comment: What database platform?  If SQL Server, Kimberly Tripp has a great explanation of why using an auto-inc is a great choice here: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/

Comment: With 500 rows per day, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Do you expect to query the `appointment` table by the artificial key value? If so, a single auto-increment key lookup might be marginally faster than the composite key lookup, which you probably won't notice anyway unless you're running a TPC-C benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely performance standpoint, using the identity key as a clustered primary key will be most efficient. From there I would do a non clustered key with a unique constraint on datetime, patientid.

Comment: I guess you assume that the primary key is the clustered one.

Comment: From a performance standpoint, yes I did.  There would be very little overhead in the B-Tree and the leaf level, by keeping the key small and fixed.

Comment: I meant that you should edit the *"the identity key will be most efficient"* to something like *"to use the identity key as the clustered key will be most efficient"*

Comment: Gotcha.  Editted.  Sometimes my hands assume everyone else can read what's in my head.